How to find path between disjointed components?
I'm trying to find the paths that will connect between disjointed components.
These are the connected components that I extracted from the graph data.
[{'F', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'G', 'S'}, {'H'}, {'I', 'K'}, {'J', 'M'}, {'L'}, {'O'}, {'N'}, {'Q'}, {'R'}, {'P'}]
The graph data (TSV) has the edge information; the graph is directed graph and unweighted.  The first couple rows of the data looks like this:

   source   destination  predicate
0    X         V             
1    U         Z 
2    K         W 
3    S         AA 
4    C         DD  

What approach will be efficient for finding the missing connections (intermediary paths or search within two or three hop-neighborhood) that will connect these disjointed components into a complete network without arbitrarily adding edges?
I was thinking creating an adjaceny list and applying either BFS or DFS but this seems like it will not be optimal interms of memory usage and time because there are 47 million edges in the graph data.

By 'disjointed components' you mean the vertices in a component are unreachable from any vertex in a different component?  That is, there is no path between the components.  So you will need to add some edges.  Whether or not the additions are 'arbitrary' depends on how you define arbitrary.  You need to clarify.  A small example ( e.g. two components each with 2 or three vertices ) with the solution you would accept is needed.

@ravenspoint so there are no path that connects between {'F', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'G', 'S'} and  {'H'} and/or {'I', 'K'}, etc correct?

You have not pasted your edge list ( or adjacency matrix ), so there is no way to tell.

@ravenspoint I did post the edge list (source, destination) just the first 5. There are over 1M in the edge list (TSV file as I refered in the post). I don't think Stack Overflow allows me to share that large list or array in the post... would be hard to post even given it has limited character space.

You need a small example that demonstrates the problem.  Once that works, you go on to the full example.

Here https://github.com/JamesBremner/so78936532/blob/main/ex1.txt is a small graph with three components each with three vertices.  Take a look and let us know how you expect to create paths between components without arbitrarily adding edges
